# Merge managed-vm and google-managed-vm tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

It looks like there's a tag for both [managed-vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managed-vm) and [google-managed-vm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-managed-vm). Should these be merged?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/managed-vm

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-managed-vm

Comment: Is there such thing as a "managed VM" that is unrelated to/unaffiliated with Google? If so, would there ever be a need to refer specifically to the Google-provided service?

Comment: I don't believe so.  A quick search only surfaces google managed VMs:  https://www.google.com/search?q=managed+vm&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari

Comment: Anything else I can answer to help here?

Comment: The [description of the `managed-vm` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/managed-vm/info) makes it quite clear that it's specifically about the Google App Engine feature for running in a more flexible environment on Google Compute Engine machines.

Comment: We'd really like to get a little traction here :'(  How can we get these merged?